# Jquery: Remove previous data in a select list

Tags: jquery, json

i had the following question.

i want to update my subcategory select list when the user select a specific leadcategory and show in other select list the subcategories.

The problem is that i can't figure out when i'm selecting a another leadcategory my previous subcategory has to remove and fill with the new data depending wich leadcategory i selected.

For now i've the following code.

The data i parse is a json encode who looks like:

```
 Website.Config = {"categorieen":{"1":{"1":"Navullingen ","2":"Potloden"},"2":{"3":"Navullingen","6":"potloden","7":"testSubcategorie"}}}


    function onChangeSubcategorie(){

 categorieen = Website.Config.categorieen;

 $("form#overviewFilter select#cat").change(function() {
  var hoofdCategorie = $(this).val();
  var subcategorieen = categorieen[hoofdCategorie];

  for(var c in subcategorieen ) {
   var tekst = subcategorieen[c];

   if(hoofdCategorie == 1) {
    $('form#overviewFilter select#scat').append("<option value="+tekst+">"+tekst+"</option>");
   }else if(hoofdCategorie == 2) {

    $('form#overviewFilter select#scat').append("<option value="+tekst+">"+tekst+"</option>");
   }
  }
 });
}
```

thank you for helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to clear #scat list first and then populate it with new data.

You can do this using next statements:

```
$('form#overviewFilter select#scat').empty();
```

or

```
$('form#overviewFilter select#scat').find('option').remove();
```

More information: [jQuery remove](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

Comment: Tnx mates i'll try that, tnx for fast feedback.

Answer (score 1):

You can clear an element's contents by calling the [`empty()` method](http://api.jquery.com/empty/), like this:

```
$('#scat').empty();
```

By the way, when you select an element by ID, you don't need anything but the ID selector (eg, `#scat`).
Since IDs are (or are *supposed to be*) unique, you don't need anything else.
jQuery optimizes for "pure" ID selectors, so `#scat` will be faster than any other selector.